# New Python print format statement return different results. Why?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

Python 2.7.5+

The new style '{X.Yf}'.format(num) doesn't seem to act like the old style '%X.Yf'%(num).  Can someone explain?

```
>>> '%8.3f' % (0.98567)
'   0.986'
>>> '%8.3f' % (1.98567)
'   1.986'

>>> '{num:8.3}'.format(num=0.98567)
'   0.986'
>>> '{num:8.3}'.format(num=1.98567)
'    1.99'
```

Note how the old style displays 3 digits after the decimal, but the new style sometimes prints 2 and sometimes 3.  Am I making some silly mistake?

Answer (score 6):

Use `f` in the new format too:

```
>>> '{num:8.3f}'.format(num=1.98567)
'   1.986'
```

Without the format type, the default is `g`, and the precision is interpreted as the *total* number of digits (not counting a 0 before the decimal). With a `1` before the declimal point, only 2 digits are shown after it.

You'd see the same output with the old string formatting if you used `g` instead of `f`:

```
>>> '%8.3g' % (1.98567)
'    1.99'
```

Comment: The term for this is significant figures.

Comment: @JackAidley Thanks! I was sticking to terminology used in the [format documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).